# Android/Eclipse: Launching app on virtual device/ real phone

Tags: android, eclipse

Using eclipse, when I launch my app on the android virtual device it is really slow as "ANDROID_" is written but the app is never executed (Before it was written no DNS servers found so I added -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 in the Window preferences)

Another problem is when I conenct my device (an alcatel onetouch) to my computer. I downloaded the driver on alcatel's website but when I want to upload the pilot and select the folder I downloaded, it is written "pilot not found"
And my phone is not recognized by Eclipse

EDIT: When I write the command "adb devices" in my console in the folder “Android SDK/platform-tools“ I only get the reference of the virtual device, not of my phone...

Answer (score 0):

Starting the emulator for the first time can take several minutes, so be patient. But afterwards you can leave it running when re-starting your app, then it is typically executed after only some seconds.

Comment: after more than 10min it's still on "android"
I  know it does not take that long :/